# Get the property value of the char left to the cursor

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

I'm creating a simple texteditor. I have a togglebutton for the bold option.

Problem:
When i have selected some text to make bold and pressed the button, it makes it bold. Now according to where i click in the richtextbox, i need to get the property value of the character on the left side of the cursor to know if the togglebutton should be toggled on or off. I hope you understand, it the same as in MS Office Word.

Here is how I'm thinking it could be done:

```
    private void richTextBox_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        TextSelection ts = //Selection of the char left of the cursor. Help wanted!

        var charValue = ts.GetPropertyValue(TextElement.FontWeightProperty);

        if ((FontWeight)charValue == FontWeights.Normal)
        {
            boldButton.IsChecked = false;
            isBold = false;
        }
        else if ((FontWeight)charValue == FontWeights.Bold)
        {
            boldButton.IsChecked = true;
            isBold = true;
        }
    }
```

EDIT:

Apparently this line does the work:

```
var charValue = richTextBox.Selection.GetPropertyValue(TextElement.FontWeightProperty);
```

Only problem now is that it requires 2 clicks for the action to happen. Its probably something to do with the Event i have selected for the richTextBox. But seemed to be the only one who worked.

It seems not to react to my newest click but the click before, giving me the value of what property the previous click text had.

FIXED:

Figured out how to use MouseLeftButtonDown event. Working code:

```
richTextBox.AddHandler(RichTextBox.MouseLeftButtonDownEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(richTextBox_MouseLeftButtonDown), true);

private void richTextBox_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var charValue = richTextBox.Selection.GetPropertyValue(TextElement.FontWeightProperty);

        if (charValue != DependencyProperty.UnsetValue && (FontWeight)charValue == FontWeights.Normal)
        {
            boldButton.IsChecked = false;
            isBold = false;
        }
        else if (charValue != DependencyProperty.UnsetValue && (FontWeight)charValue == FontWeights.Bold)
        {
            boldButton.IsChecked = true;
            isBold = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

There is a property called [`CaretPostion`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.caretposition%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that tells you where the cursor is. I think that is all that you need.